# AMD Hybrid graphics, hide intel gpu? 13.04

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, 13.04

Clearly no one seems to be able to find an easy way to fix this.  Im pretty sure the issue is the Intel driver conflicting with the Catalyst driver, this was fixed for a while in 12.10 by someone downgrading it in a ppa.  Anyway Is there any way to just disable the intel gpu and run pure AMD gpu.  I know you can blacklist the amd but have had no luck with the intel.   Or can someone make a fake intel driver that still lets you boot up in AMD, just dont switch to intel and it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Someone did it, it's in the “Old hybrid graphics works” thread posted by BastiFantasti.

This guy's guide works http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=76

> Hi there,
>
> I've managed to install the fglrx driver and use the external graphics adapter. The problem is the new intel graphics driver.
>
> Here's what I did:
>
> Ensure that you have the deb files for the current AMD driver (created with --buildpkg as described in previous posts)
>
> 1. open a shell and download a previous version of the intel driver and it's dependencies:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir temp
>    cd temp
>    wget hxxp://launchpadlibrarian.net/119461148/libudev0_175-0ubuntu13_i386.deb
>    wget hxxp://launchpadlibrarian.net/111621162/xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.20.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
>    ```
> 2. remove the eventually installed fglrx and the installed intel drivers. When removing the intel driver let it remove both packages
>
>    ```
>    cd ..
>    sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
>    sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
>    ```
> 3. install the older driver with its dependencies
>
>    ```
>    cd temp
>    sudo dpkg -i libudev*
>    sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.20.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
>    ```
> 4. now install the fglrx packages (go to the folder containing the fglrx deb files). Warnings about defect link groups can be ignored (at least I did )
>
>    ```
>    cd sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
>    ```
> 5. backup and remove the existing xorg.conf
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
>    ```
> 6. create a new config file and switch to the external graphics adapter
>
>    ```
>    sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
>    sudo aticonfig --initial -f
>    ```
> 7. reboot

That said, for 64-bit I had to pull the files from other sources than the ones listed in the post. Then in Synaptic I locked the Intel drivers so they could not upgrade.

Comment: I have the same problem as the OP. Can you provide URLs to the 64-bit sources? I can't seem to find the ones I need.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/2:2.20.2-1ubuntu1/+build/3696669